# Does java not allow two List element modifications within the same iteration?

Tags: java, collections, iteration, concurrentmodification

I am having trouble understanding this error.
Error message: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
public static int lift(List<String> list) {
        int index = 0;
        for (String element : list) {
            list.remove(index);
            list.add(index, element.toUpperCase());
            index++;
        }
```

I'm trying to replace list items but I guess removing and adding in the same iteration is considered a concurrent modification? Is that right? I tried element = element.toUppercase() but that wasn't actually modifying the list at all...

Please help! I am a beginner (obviously)

Comment: The easiest way would be `list.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);`.

Comment: The closest thing to your current code would be to remove the `list.remove` line, and then use `list.set` instead of `list.add`. That would work without ConcurrentModificationException; but it is not efficient for all list types (e.g. LinkedList would be inefficient).

Comment: A generally efficient looping way would be: `for (ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) { it.set(it.next().toUpperCase()); }`